# image displaying in java

Tags: java, image, display

i have tried this code,the code is running but not showing any image..

i have saved this file as image.java

and also tell me if there is a problem in the adress..

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Image {

    public static void main(String avg[]) throws IOException
    {
       image abc=new image();
    }

    public void DisplayImage() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\snakeandladder.jpg"));
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(200,300);
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't invoke `DisplayImage()`, Try `abc.DisplayImage();` in your main()

Answer (score 0):

I am not good in programming,but don't you have to call the function by using object like abc.DisplayImage(); in main function.I am not sure about this..